# RecyclerView Crashing - Android Codelab

Tags: android-recyclerview, google-codelab

I was running through an Android Codelab but it keeps crashing. Could anyone help me with why?

Below is a copy of the error logs, and more than happy to posta ny of the other elements to understand that situation.

Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 25: /data/app/~~3X-J2HR2s4vvUVvcwC0e4Q==/com.example.test-a_LLNNa-RIZlAk8hi-Qpcg==/base.apk
2023-08-10 10:56:38.699 25500-25500 AndroidRuntime          pid-25500                            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.test, PID: 25500
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4169)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:926)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:889)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:772)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:13)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067) 
2023-08-10 11:44:33.708 10493-10493 AndroidRuntime          pid-10493                            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.test, PID: 10493
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4169)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:926)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:889)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:772)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:13)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067) 
--------- beginning of main

Code from Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".drink_list_1920" >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/DrinkRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="729dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>



Main code 


import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.speakeasy.data.Drinksource

class DrinkList1920 : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drink_list_1920, container, false)


    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val myDrink = Drinksource().loadDrinks()

        val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.DrinkRecyclerView)



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that one of the first lines in your stack trace states that:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: **You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
> theme (or descendant) with this activity**.

Since you have not added code in your question, it is hard to discern from where exactly it is coming from, so I can only offer guesses:

1. Inside your AndroidManifest.xml file, the activity in question has a wrong theme

> ```
> <activity android:theme="@android:style/ThEME_EXAMPLE" >
> ```

Maybe try replacing it with this:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

2. Your activity is not subclassing the correct type of Android activity (you should be using Activity)

There could be other possible origins of this issue, but without seeing the code in question, it is quite hard to pinpoint the problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Ashley - If my answer helped you, please mark it as such.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I have added more information above!

Comment: @Ashley - Please add the AndroidManifest.xml file.